# A UML way to describe a key/value datastore?

Tags: uml, key-value, diagram, berkeley-db

I'm currently writing the documentation for a database using berkeleyDB. I'd like to draw UML diagram describing the keys and the values of the datastores. Is there a 'standard' way to describe this kind of database using UML ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Just a [class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) with two properties. One for the key, one for the value. Do keep in mind that an [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) design is meant for documentation purposes only, although some UML editors are capable of generating code based upon your model.

Of course, you could also use an [Activity model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) to show how this table interacts with others. Or a [Use Case diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram) which shows how the data is handled by the actors.

There are more kinds of diagrams, though. The one you need depends on what you want to tell about your project.

Answer (score 1):

The proper MDA way to do this is to use a Class or Object diagram, use a Class or Object for each table, add a property for each database field.  Define Stereotypes for PK, FK, Unique, Index and attach them to each field as appropriate.  Join each Table object with associations.    Depending on the tool you use you can probably attach each end of the associations to specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am more in favour of a stricter adherence to the NoSQL database’s structure and behaviour. Thus a key value model for Base would differ albeit slightly from MongoDB or from DynamoDB but it would reduce the bias towards the people who have to implement the model. E.g. in DynamoDB I would have a main table with the partition and sort key as well as less relevant attributes and put the attributes eligible for secondary indexes in separate tables.